# Bash script or existing program to monitor "etc/hosts" file domain blacklist access?

Tags: linux, bash, monitor, hosts

This is sort of a complex question, I hope I can explain it clearly:

I have a long blacklist of domains added to my /etc/hosts file and it works perfectly. Now I want to be able to "monitor" with a "simple" Bash script every time a domain/entry is blocked, e.g.:

Let's say I'm running this hypothetical script on my Terminal and I try to access Facebook in my browser (which is blocked in my hosts file), I'd like to see in my Terminal something like:

```
0.0.0.0 facebook.com
```

Then, I try to access LinkedIn (also blocked), and now I want to see in my Terminal:

```
0.0.0.0 facebook.com
0.0.0.0 linkedin.com
```

Then, I try to access Instagram (blacklisted as well) and I see:

```
0.0.0.0 facebook.com
0.0.0.0 linkedin.com
0.0.0.0 instagram.com
```

And so on...

Is that possible? I've spent days looking for an existing program that does this but no luck..

Comment: what does this `hypothetical script` (aka `big black hole`) actually do? does it check `/etc/hosts` for a blacklist violation, print a message, and abort? does it try to connect to the internet (eg, `wget`), get an error message, parse the error message (and map error message to entry in `/etc/hosts`)?

Comment: what do you mean by `access Facebook`?  what command are you using to `'access' Facebook`?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear in the main post... by "access Facebook" I mean going to my browser (Firefox) and type "https://www.facebook.com/"... Since is currently blacklisted (pointing to 0.0.0.0 in my hosts file), I get the usual "Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at www.facebook.com" message... But I want a script to show me if/when I or any program in my computer tries to access any of my blacklisted entries in my host file... And I want this scrip to keep running, monitoring access and showing which sites/entries got blocked.

Comment: I think it would be easier to run your own DNS, block said hosts and evaluate its logs.

Comment: choose a prviate class a or b network  that you don't already use; assign your domain names to distinct addresses in that network;  tcpdump or similar for accesses to the network; lookup the domain name from the logged ip.

Comment: @markp-fuso Server Fault is really for professional server admins (["managing information technology systems in a business environment"](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic)), not for home users who might need to set up a local service. [Super User](https://superuser.com) would be more appropriate for this.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible; whether you find it **simple** is a different question.

Caveat: if you edit the hosts file you'll need to restart the process.

Save

```
BEGIN {
        while (getline < "/etc/hosts")   # read the hosts file line by line
        {
                split($0,fields," *")    # break up each line on "any number of spaces" and assign to the array "fields"
                hosts[fields[2]"."]++    # create an array "hosts" that holds e.g. www.google.com as it's key
        }
        close("/etc/hosts")              # close the hosts file, be tidy
}
{
        for(a=7;a<=NF;a++){              # for each line of input (these are now coming from tcpdump)  iterate over the 7th to last (NF) fields
                if($a in hosts){         # if the field is present in the hosts array (matches an index)
                        print $a         # print it
                }
        }
}
```

as e.g. hosts.awk ...

You can then run

```
sudo tcpdump -l port 53 | awk -f hosts.awk
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! so far is not working, but it might just need some small change somewhere... I created the .awk file in my hope folder and ran the command in the Terminal. I didn't see the expected output, so I ran just the tcpdump part of the command and is capturing traffic as expected, so it seems like the problem lies somewhere in the awk command (but I have no idea where... my Terminal knowledge is not that good.

Comment: Well ... it needs a verbatim match at this stage; so www.google.com != google.com ... but that could be worked on.

Comment: Again, I'm not very good with scripting, so I don't really understand the meaning of the content in the .awk file... the verbatim match might be what is failing... If the script is parsing the /etc/hosts file by line, then the "0.0.0.0" part at the beginning of each line is probably messing things up... Am I right? if that's the case, what could be done? Thanks.

Comment: I understand a little bit better the script, but there are still some questions... Although, would it be possible to somehow "simplify" the script for awk to just print anything that matches whatever that comes after "0.0.0.0 "?... Something like: "read the hosts file line by line, pick the lines that have "0.0.0.0 " in them and use whatever comes after "0.0.0.0 " in each of those lines to do the comparison?

Comment: That's what it does for me when I add e.g. facebook.com and linkedin.com to my hosts file.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but if I type in the Terminal something like "echo facebook.com | awk -f hosts.awk"... it should print "facebook.com" because it's in my hosts file... right? Because I'm trying that and is not working. My hosts file is HUGE (1.1M entries, 32 Megabytes file), I imagine that slows down the initialization of the command, but it should still work... right?

Comment: No, it wouldn't.  You'd have to start at `a=1` for that particular echo statement to trigger.  And that *is* huge.  I don't know how much RAM it would consume to build the array, or how long initialisation should take, but I'd expect it to be hefty.

Comment: Sorry for the LATE reply! I a tiny bit more familiar with AWK and at least now I understand what you meant with the comment "You'd have to start at a=1 for that particular echo statement to trigger"... Well, I changed the line "for(a=7;a<=NF;a++){" to "for(a=1;a<=NF;a++){" and then ran the command "echo facebook.com | awk -f hosts.awk" and still nothing happens. I ran the echo command with other hosts present in my /etc/hosts tile as well, but still no luck... So again, would it be possible to just do something like "awk '/^0.0.0.0/" and pick the "$2" field in those lines of my hosts file?

Comment: It's been a while that I dreamt that up; I think you'd have to `echo facebook.com.`  ... not the trailing dot!  @tuqueque Because that's how tcpdump would output names, and that's how I construct the index of the array `hosts[fields[2]"."]++`  ... note the `.` in the quotes.